# Byte array outputstream

Tags: java, arrays, byte, outputstream

Stupid question probably but what is the ideal length for a byte array to send over an `outputstream`? I couldn't find anything about this online.

I have found a lot of example that set their array size equal to 2^X or something similar. But what is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no optimal size. OutputStream is an abstract concept; there are a million implementations of it. (Not just 'FileOutputStream is an implementation', but 'FileOutputStream, on OpenJDK11, on Windows 10, with this servicepack, with this CPU and this much system memory, under these circumstances').

The reason you see that is for buffer efficiency. The problem with sending 1 byte is usually basically nothing, but sometimes, sending 1 (or very few) bytes results in this nasty scenario:

1. you send one byte.
2. The underlying outputstream isn't designed to buffer that byte, it doesn't have the storage for it, so the only thing it can do is send it onwards to the actual underlying resource. Let's say the OutputStream represents a file on the filesystem.
3. The kerneldriver for this works similarly. (Most OSes do buffer internally, but you can ask the OS not to do this when you open the file).
4. Therefore, that one byte now needs to be written to disk. However, it is an SSD, and you can't do that to an SSD, you can only write an entire cell at once*. That's just how SSDs work: You can only write an entire block's worth. They aren't bits in sequence on a big platter.
5. So, the kernel reads the entire cell out, updates the one byte you are writing, and writes the entire cell back to the SSD.
6. Your actual loop does write, say, about 50,000 bytes, so something that should have taken a single SSD read and write, now takes 50,000 reads and 50,000 writes, burning through your SSD cell longevity and taking 50,000 times longer than needed.

Similar issues occur for networking (end up sending a single byte, wrapped in HTTP headers, wrapped in 2 TCP/IP packets, resulting in sending ~1000 bytes over the network for each byte you `.write(singleValue)` and many other such systems.

### So why don't these streams buffer?

Because there are cases where you don't actually want them to do this; there are plenty of reasons to write I/O with specific efficiency in mind.

### Is there no way to just let something to this for me?

Ah, you're in luck, there is! `BufferedWriter` and friends (`BufferedOutputStream` exists as well) wrap around an underlying stream and buffer for you:

```
var file = new FileOutputStream("/some/path");
var wrapped = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
file.write(1); // this is a bad idea
wrapped.write(1); // this is fine
```

Here, the wrapped write doesn't result in anything happening except some memory being shoved around. No bytes are written to disk (with the downside that if someone trips over a powercable, it's just lost). Only after you close `wrapped`, or call `flush()` on wrapped, or write some sufficient amount of bytes to `wrapped`, will wrapped end up actually sending a whole bunch of bytes to the underlying stream. **This is what you should use if making a byte array is unwieldy**. Why reinvent the wheel?

### But I want to write to the underlying raw stream

Well, you're using too few bytes if the amount of bytes is less than what a single TCP/IP packet can hold, or an unfortunate size otherwise (imagine the TCP/IP packet can hold 1000 bytes exactly, and you send 1001 and bytes. That's one full packet, and then a second packet with just 1 byte, giving you only 50% efficiency. 50% is still better than 0.1% efficiency which byte-at-a-time would get you in this hypothetical). But, if you send, say, 5001 bytes, that's 5 full packets and one regrettable 1-byte packet, for 83.35% efficiency. Unfortunate it's not near 100, but not nearly as bad. Same applies to disk (if an SSD cell holds 2048 bytes and you send 65537 bytes, it's still ~96/7% efficient).

You're using too many bytes if the impact on your own java process is such that this becomes problematic: It's causing excessive garbage collection, or, worse, out of memory errors.

So where is the 'sweet spot'? Depends a little bit, but `65536` is common and is unlikely to be 'too low'. Unless you run many thousands of simultaneous threads, it's not too high either.

It's usually a power of 2 mostly because of superstition, but there is some sense in it: Those underlying buffer things are often a power of two (computers are binary things, after all). So if the cell size happens to be, say, 2048, well, then you are 100% efficient if you send 65536 bytes (that's exactly 32 cells worth of data).

But, the only thing you're really trying to avoid is that 0.1% efficiency rate which occurs if you write one byte at a time to a packetizing (SSD, network, etc) underlying stream. Hence, it doesn't matter, as long as it's more than 2048 or so, you should already have avoided the doom scenario.

*) I'm oversimplifying; the point is that a single byte read or write can take as long as a whole chunk of them, and to give some hint as to why that is, not to do a complete deep-dive on SSD technology.